# How do you stop a TextWriterTraceListener from appending using app.config?

Tags: c#, logging, app-config, tracesource

I'm using System.Diagnostics.TraceSource for logging and one of my listeners is a TextWriterTraceListener. In the tracing primer [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2005/03/15/396431.aspx) it sets this up as follows:

```
<listeners>
  <add initializeData="output.txt" 
       type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
       name="myLocalListener" />
</listeners>
```

The problem is that this will always append to output.txt. How do you alter this to an overwrite in the config file?

Programmatically the listener I want is a:

```
new TextWriterTraceListener(new StreamWriter("output.txt", false));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to make your own.

I suggest that you inherit from `TextWriterTraceListener` and in your constructor set the base `Writer` to what you proposed: `new StreamWriter("output.txt", false)`.

Some sample code:

```
public class MyTextWriterTraceListener : TextWriterTraceListener
{
    public MyTextWriterTraceListener(string logFileName)
        : base(logFileName)
    {
        base.Writer = new StreamWriter(logFileName, false);
    }
}
```

This lets you take the `initializeData` parameter from a configuration file to specify the name of the file, or specify one if created in code.

Comment: I like the idea, but when specifying the type in the App.config `type=MyNamespace.MyTextWriterTraceListener` the program crashes.

Comment: Interesting.  I made a similar custom listener just the other day and had no problems.  The one bit that I had to add into my app.config was `type="MyNamespace.MyTextWriterTraceListener, AssemblyNameContainingListener"`.  Also make sure that the assembly containing it is being copied, I had a unit test that referenced it in the app.config but not in the code so Visual Studio was helpful enough to not copy it local.

Comment: Thanks, I was leaving off the assembly name.

Answer (score 2):

I know this doesn't directly answer your question, but use [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) instead. It does more stuff than out-of-the-box diagnostics in terms of logging options and it's really easy to use.

Comment: -1 doesn't answer the question at all.  OP wasn't asking for alternative logging solutions but rather how to configure the one chosen.

Comment: @JonPeterson I disagree. There is a reasonable chance that this answer will be helpful to somebody, somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Even more simpler, just tell the TestWriterTraceListener to not append the file:

```
TextWriterTraceListener twtl = new TextWriterTraceListener(new StreamWriter(@"<path to my logfile>", false));
```

By selecting `false` the logfile is overwritten each time you initialize the TextWriterTraceListener.

Comment: Thank you, but I was looking for a solution that would allow specification of the writer in config. Your solution is at the bottom of the question as the behaviour I would like to replicate :)